# Drawing Chart.js Bubble Chart with Rectangles

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I know it kind of goes against the name, but does anyone know how to draw a rectangle instead of the default circle for a chart.js bubble chart? Ideally this would be able to take parameters for the horizontal and vertical dimensions.

So for example:

```
p: 52.627417,
h: 17.000000,
v: 16.031220
```

Where p is the perimeter, h is the horizontal and v is the vertical.